Adding links to Help Center of SaaS product
I need to add more information about how our product works and link to our Help Center, the requirements for this task are:

to link to an outside help center
make it quick to develop
it needs to be consistent throughout the product and have a "specific place"

We already have a general link to the help center, and using a sidebar to open more instructions would break the second point.
Putting a link inside a tooltip seems counterintuitive, and would deter from actually reading the useful tooltips we already have.
I saw some SaaS products use a little information icon that you hover, but then they would have to be personalized.
I don't want to add buttons in each page of the SaaS product to link to 5 separate help center pages.

Can you add images to visualize the problem?

You can have a chat like button fixed to the bottom right quadrant as most teams do.

This could open up a modal with the rest of the links you want to show.

I wanted to do this too, but my team wanted a quick fix so we ended up opting for html links

@floi that can be frustrating, if it gets to you, there's always space for you on the dev side. HTML --> css --> js (es5) --> js (es6) --> typescript. In that order, skip the first js if you lazy. Ux engineers are sort after, but it requires experience
